# failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /charts/requirements.txt]

Tags: python-3.x, docker, macos, pip, user-management

### ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /charts/requirements.txt

> [4/5] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /charts/requirements.txt:
> #0 1.873 Processing /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-103/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> #0 1.883 ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/python3-103/six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
> #0 1.883
> #0 2.135 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.0 is available.
> #0 2.135 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I already tried to upgrade pip3 with /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
but i get this other error

WARNING: The directory '/Users/josuenavarro/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./ambiente_charts/lib/python3.8/site-packages (23.0)

Comment: Please show the text of your `/charts/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Your docker  build logs show that its referencing a resource that *should* only ever exist in macOS (`/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library...`)

Make sure that you aren't copying your system python or python libraries from your host into your docker build (i.e. copying your local virtualenv).